# Does the new Badge Progress indicator make sense in every review page?

Tags: feature-request, review, badge-progress

The new Badge Progress indicator shows common badge progress for [**Civic Duty**](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/32/civic-duty), [**Copy Editor**](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/223/copy-editor), [**Electorate**](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/155/electorate) (common - in every review page). The `Copy Editor` badge progress is okay for that. But `Civic Duty` and `Electorate` badge progress indications are not required in the *Suggested Edits* and *Low Quality Posts* review page.
 Because

[image]

So it's a request to remove the badge progress indicators for `Civic Duty` and `Electorate` from the *Suggested Edits* and *Low Quality Posts* review pages.
Instead add the [**Proofreader**](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1276/proofreader) in the *Suggested Edits* review page.

> **Proofreader:** Approved or rejected 100 suggested edits.

Also, [**Archaeologist**](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1286/archaeologist) can be added (just a suggestion not a request) on both review page as we can edit from both review page.

> **Archaeologist:** Edited 100 posts that were inactive for 6 months.

Comment: Civic Duty? Why on Earth would we need a progress indicator for that? Why not just go look at your profile page? -.-