# Hide obtained and/or irrelevant badges from badge progress review queue

Tags: feature-request, review, badges, badge-progress

There's a badge progress popup in the review queue, which (independently of the queue you're in) shows your progress towards the Civic Duty, Copy Editor and Electorate badges.

- Unlike the badge tracker on your profile page, badges you've already obtained aren't hidden.
- Some queues, like the Close Votes queue, don't allow voting on posts. Showing the Civic Duty and Electorate badge there (see below) doesn't really make sense. (See also [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149936/295232) which suggests alternatives; I like that suggestion but maybe it's simpler just to hide the current ones.)

[image]